# Inserting a double variable in JOptionPane

Tags: java

Im new to java and im having trouble with the code below. Im trying to convert a double variable to a string variable to use it in JOptionPane.showMessagedialog but its giving me an error which is listed below.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class pricecalculatorchap5

{
   public static void main(String [] args)

   {
         String priceinput;
         double wholesaleprice;
         double markupprice;
         double retailprice;
         String retailprice2;
         String pricecalculated;

     priceinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the whole sale price of the item.");
     wholesaleprice = Double.parseDouble(priceinput);


          priceinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the markeup price of the item.");
          markupprice = Double.parseDouble(priceinput);


     retailprice = ( (markupprice / 100) * wholesaleprice) + wholesaleprice;
     retailprice2 = Double.toString (retailprice);



     pricecalculated = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The price of the item is calculated as  " +  retailprice2 );  


   }
}
```

---

> **ERROR**
>
> pricecalculatorchap5.java:28: error: no suitable method found for
>   showMessageDialog(String)
>        pricecalculated = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The price of the item is calculated as  " +  retailprice2 );
>                                     ^
>       method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon) is not
>   applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) 1 error

Answer (score 0):

`showMessageDialog` always together with a `Component`. There are serveral method override but none of them have only String parameter like you using. [Refer Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))